# Display 2 floats rounded up to 2 decimal places without losing which one is bigger

Tags: java, string, floating-point, formatting, double

I get two numbers `num1` and `num2` from a network service that can be represented by a double and have an unknown number of decimal places (I mean could be 3, 4 or 5 etc).
These numbers represent a percentage so could be something like 0.34567 which is 34.567%
I need to display them with 2 decimal places (or no decimal places instead of e.g. 34.00%) if `num1` is greater than `num2`.

I tried the following:

```
String num1 = "0.3547";  
String num2 = "0.354";  

int fixed = 2;  
int diff = Math.abs(num1.length() - num2.length());  
double tmp = 0.0d;  
double d1 = Double.valueOf(num1);  
double d2 = Double.valueOf(num2);  
tmp = (d1 > d2)? d1 : d2;  
while(diff > 0) {  
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("%.");  
    sb.append(String.valueOf(fixed + diff)).append("f");  
    String formatter = sb.toString();  
    System.out.println(formatter);  
    String round = String.format(formatter, tmp);  
    tmp = Double.parseDouble(round);  
    --diff;  
}  

String final1 = String.format("%.2f", tmp);  
String final2 = String.format("%.2f", (d1 < d2)? d1 : d2);  
System.out.println(final1 + " vs " + final2);
```

The output is:

0.36 vs 0.35

How sane is this approach and the result? May be I am thinking this wrong?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @talex: How would that help in showing 2 digits?

Comment: @talex: Please check update in post

Answer (score -1):

For ceation of two decimal places just do:

```
num = (Maht.round(num * 10_000))
num /= 10_000
```

If you just divide by 100 instead of 10_000 you get directly percent.

and for removing zeros just convert the number to a String with

```
String.valueOf(num)
```

and search for the regex pattern

```
"\\.0"
```

and act accordingly by removing it if it is found.

Complet solution (a bit diffrent, because I had some trouble with regex):

```
//Rounding on to two decimalplaces and writing to a String    
numX = (Math.round(numX * 10_000));
String numXStr = String.valueOf(numX /= 100);
//Removing of ".0" endings
if (numXStr .endsWith(".0")) {
  numXStr = numXStr .substring(0, numXStr .length() - 2);
}
numXStr += "%"; //Adding the percent char at the end
System.out.println(numXStr) //outputting
```

Comment: This gives 35 for both numbers

Comment: Yes it outputs 35.47% and 35.4%, bcause you said you want two deicimalplaces if neccessary. For "0.31" it would output 31% or do you want no decimalplaces in the final String so that "0.123" would become 12% and "0.456" to 46%?

Comment: No, it only gives `35`. No decimal places. I tested it

Comment: what?, I copied that code one to one (and added that semicolon in the end) into my eclipse and it outputed decimal places. So i don't know what is wrong. numX generated I so: 
Double numX = Double.valueOf(num1)

Comment: When I run this I get `35`. Code: `String num1 = "0.3547";
  String num2 = "0.354";
  
  
  double d1 = Double.parseDouble(num1);
  int number1 = (int)Math.round(d1 * 10000);
  String num1ToNumber = String.valueOf(number1/=100);
  System.out.println("num1 = " + num1ToNumber);
  `

Comment: If I use `Double.parseDouble(num2)` I also get `35`

Comment: your code messes up at `String num1ToNumber = String.valueOf(number1/=100)` because you are trying to get decimal places division witch acts like `(int) (number1/=100)` and there for every thing is floored
try this
`double d1 = Double.parseDouble(num1);
int number1 = (int) Math.round(d1 * 10000);
double d11 = (double) number1 / 100;
String num1ToNumber = String.valueOf(d11);
System.out.println("num1 = " + num1ToNumber);`
It is your code with one line added and if it still does not work try your debug mod of you IDE with a breakpoint a the beginning and track you variables.